# How to flip a VRML file (.wrl), or flip the VR model in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vrml, wrl

I have a fairly complex VRML model of a prosthetic right hand in a .wrl file (3 Megabytes) which I am manipulating (animating according to commands) in Matlab.  I'd like to make a mirror image (**horizontal flip**) of the file (to be a left hand).  I do not mind whether I use a free program to process the file (which I imagine should just involve mirroring all the horizontal co-ordinates) or if there is a Matlab command that can flip a VR model, but I haven't been able to find a solution.  There's nothing else in the "world" so everything within the file can be flipped.

There are named transforms in the file and I need them to keep their names, because those joints get animated, but it's not a problem if I have to change the sign of the rotations to get things moving in the correct mirrored direction.

I'm just looking for a simple and free solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest to do this manually. The easiest solution would be to export your model to a .max or any other file that you can open with a 3D modeling program (3dsmax, DeepExploration, Maya, etc.) Once you have the new file, that you can open with any of these programs, I think it's much easier to do your job. Usually you can do it using the interface by dragging or clicking buttons, not manually going through the coordinate values :)